# Qt Creator Tests GUI does not run my GoogleTest unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, qt-creator, googletest

I was wondering if there is something that I am missing / not understanding in the whole process so I am after some help if anyone has an idea. I have a CMake project that has various tests that are implemented using google test.

Test are generated fine and I can run them all using the "test" target of cmake (even through Qt Creator). However, when I am using the "Tests" GUI of Qt Creator not all of my tests just run.

If I right click and select "Run All Tests" only 5 test are run.
If I select a test and then "Run This Test" pretty much nothing happens.
I just get a message `0 Passes, 0 Fails`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this was a bug with the version that I was using 4.3.1. I ended up founding a few bugs listed in Qt Creator bugtracker related to CMake and unit testing that were fixed in 4.5.0

Comment: I can not confirm the error but can confirm that QtCreator 4.4.0 and GTest and CMake work together. I can run single tests but can also run all tests. See http://www.th-thielemann.de/development/cmake/cmake_unittest_gtest.html

Comment: Here is the comment on their bug tracker https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-17882?focusedCommentId=350791&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-350791

Comment: I do not see the error in QtCreator 4.4.0 even in the bugtracker the target version is 4.5.0.